# Python variable file path and string prefixes

Tags: python, string, variables, f-string

Using tkinter to select output folder for processed files.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_output = filedialog.askdirectory()
x = "NAME"


file_output 
>>>'C:/Users/person/Documents/'
```

Would like to use `file_output` and `x` as variables for my file path,
My attempt:

```
df.to_csv(f"{file_output}/{x} 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv")

print((f"{file_output}/{x} 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv"))
>>> C:/Users/person/Documents/NAME 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv
```

This does not work in my program. The output I need is

```
C:\\Users\\person\\Documents\\NAME 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv
```

I am reading the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringprefix

Still don't understand how to escape or a workaround, Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily use `replace` to get the output you want, so try this:

```py
df.to_csv((f"{file_output}/{x} 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv").replace('/', '\\\\'))

print((f"{file_output}/{x} 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv").replace('/', '\\\\'))
```

output:

```
C:\\Users\\person\\Documents\\NAME 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv
```

Comment: My output: `C:\Users\person\Documents\NAME 6-30-22 11s & 12s.csv` when using your answer

Comment: try 4 of '\' so use `replace('\', '\\\\')`